# How to recover from intermittent 'the resource eth_call is not available' during runtime?

Tags: web3.py, web3-providers, network, rpc, connections

When I call a contract function using a `block_identifier` from the past,
I get error code `-32002` `the resource eth_call is not available` in ~4/5 times
when using a public RPC using Python web3.
~1/5 times the call succeeds.

The issue though is that I need to rerun the whole script for a successful attempt to occur.
I am not able to recover during script runtime, where the call always returns
the same error once it happens.

I tried various things like deleting and re-initializing all the things, waiting,
using a custom requests session and reloading the `web3` module with `importlib`.
The only way to recover is to rerun the whole script.

The interesting thing is that once it works, I am in a state where I can repeat
the call any amount of times and it won't fail.

Any idea what I'm missing and how I can reset the state during runtime?

Minimal executable exmaple that reproduces:

```py
import importlib
import time

import requests
import web3


# Some data
wbnb_address = "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c"
busd_address = "0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56"

pcs_v2_router_address = "0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E"
minimal_router_abi = [
    {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'uint256',
                 'name': 'amountIn',
                 'type': 'uint256'},
                {'internalType': 'address[]', 'name': 'path', 'type': 'address[]'}],
     'name': 'getAmountsOut',
     'outputs': [{'internalType': 'uint256[]',
                  'name': 'amounts',
                  'type': 'uint256[]'}],
     'stateMutability': 'view',
     'type': 'function'}
]
historic_block = 24900000

# Poor man's public RPC
provider_uri = "https://bsc-dataseed2.defibit.io/"


def main():
    # Init all the things
    adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=20, pool_maxsize=20)
    session = requests.Session()
    session.mount('https://', adapter)

    provider = web3.Web3.HTTPProvider(provider_uri, session=session)
    w3 = web3.Web3(provider)

    contract = w3.eth.contract(address=pcs_v2_router_address, abi=minimal_router_abi)

    amount_bnb_wei = web3.Web3.toWei(1.0, "ether")
    fun = contract.functions.getAmountsOut(amount_bnb_wei, [wbnb_address, busd_address])

    error_count = 0
    amount_out_wei = None
    while amount_out_wei is None:
        try:
            amount_out_wei = fun.call(block_identifier=historic_block)
        except ValueError as e:
            # Once this returns {'code': -32002, 'message': 'the resource eth_call is not available.'}
            # it will do it forever.
            print(f"{e.__str__()} {error_count}")
            error_count += 1

            # Reload all the things
            del fun
            del contract
            del w3
            del provider
            session.close()
            del session
            adapter.close()
            del adapter
            importlib.reload(web3)
            importlib.reload(requests)
            time.sleep(5)

            adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=20, pool_maxsize=20)
            session = requests.Session()
            session.mount('https://', adapter)

            provider = web3.Web3.HTTPProvider(provider_uri, session=session)
            w3 = web3.Web3(provider)
            contract = w3.eth.contract(address=pcs_v2_router_address, abi=minimal_router_abi)
            fun = contract.functions.getAmountsOut(amount_bnb_wei, [wbnb_address, busd_address])

    print(f"Got amount out: {amount_out_wei}")

    # If it succeeds once, all the successive calls will work as well. Even with different parameters.
    while True:
        amount_bnb_wei -= 1
        fun = contract.functions.getAmountsOut(amount_bnb_wei, [wbnb_address, busd_address])
        amount_out_wei = fun.call(block_identifier=historic_block)
        print(f"Got amount out: {amount_out_wei} again!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: There isn't much you could do with a public RPC. They don't hold data for too long. So either you can run your own node, or use a pay RPC provider.